# How to provide some space between two lines of same text in css

Tags: html, css

Below is a screen shot of my mega menu.

I have given line-height of 14px. But, how can I provide some more spaces between the text which are broken to next line due to lacking of enough width.

I have not given any `<br>` tags anywhere. As you can see in the picture the text **device & memory storage**, **Printers & scanners & fax machines** etc words are broken to next line so I just want to provide some spaces between these lines of text.

If I'm increasing line-height its applying for all, but I don't want that, I want it to apply only for the broken text. Please, can anybody help with this?

[image]

Comment: if every column is an `ul>li` you may assign different line-height to `ul` and `li`. Or just assign a line-height to each `li` and make some space between items with `padding-top/bottom`. I should see the markup before post this suggestion as an answer

Comment: afaik there is no api that flags the occurrence of word-wrapping. however, you can detect the height of elements and compare it against the height of a baseline elment that is guaranteed not to be wrapped. the result would be the condition upon which you allot more spacing.

Comment: yes all is placed in ul li tag only.

Comment: good, so I wrote my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if every column is an `ul > li` you may assign different line-height both to `ul` and `li`.

Or just assign a line-height to each `li` and make some space between items with a `padding-top/bottom`.

As a side note, the `line-height` could be set with relative units (e.g. `em`, `rem`) or no units at all (e.g `line-height: 1.4;`) so this value is relative to the user base font-size

Comment: yeah it works for me.. it will support on all browser ?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure this works on every browser released in the past 15 years :)

Comment: ok..thanks .. i just replaced 14px to 1.1 and I got some more spaces between broken text. thanks again for saving my more time.

Answer (score 0):

increase line-height value of `li` which belong to sub menus and try to give more space in between, if needed